# Can't install TFS plugin in Android studio

Tags: android, tfs, android-studio

i Downloaded TFS plugin from below URL and add it my Android Studio. But when i am trying to open it is showing in RED colour. Please help me out how to resolve this.

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4578?pr=phpStorm&showAllUpdates=true

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

*TFS Integration* is only supported in **Intellij Idea Ultimate Edition** while
**Android Studio** is based on code of **Intellij Idea Community Edition** so it can't support *TFS integration*. Why *Google* will supply anything for free which is being sold by *Jetbrains*.
See [Version Control](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/version_control.html) and [Features Comparison](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) pages.

#### Update

If you are not already aware, checkout [Team Foundation Server - Version Control Integration](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7961?pr=androidstudio). An *under-development* and *open source* alternative.
[Visual Studio Team Services](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7981-visual-studio-team-services) plugin by Microsoft is also available now. See [installation instructions](https://java.visualstudio.com/Downloads/androidstudioplugin/Index).

Comment: Then, is there any alternative for Android studio to connect Team Foundation Server.

Comment: The answer is no for now.You can use clients like Team Explorer Everywere http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30661.

Comment: Eclipse IDE is also an open source and provides TFS plugin for free. Why not AS?

Comment: The same answer again.Because AS is based on intellij idea community and jetbrain has made TFS a premium feature so how google can derive it from jetbrain for free. I hope either jetbrain will make it free in future or someone will develop an alternative plugin.

Comment: `Team Foundation Server - Version Control Integration` has worked flawlessly for me so far! I'm able to safely (& easily) make the switch to AS with TFS.

Answer (score 4):

The **Official Version of TFS plugin** is available in [Android Studio Plugin Repository](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7981?pr=androidstudio). Installation instructions are available at [Visual Studio Team Services Plugin for Android Studio](https://java.visualstudio.com/Downloads/androidstudioplugin/Index).

> The Team Services plugin for Android Studio is available in the
>   Android Studio Plugin Repository. The plugin can be installed from
>   Android Studio by browsing the Plugin Repository.
>
> 1. In Android Studio, **open plugin settings**:
>
>    - **Linux**: from the File menu, select Settings... then Plugins
>    - **Mac**: from the Android Studio menu, select Preferences... then Plugins
>    - **Windows**: from the File menu, select Settings... then Plugins
> 2. Click the Browse repositories... button and **search for "Visual Studio Team Services"**.
> 3. Click the Install plugin button and restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to use [GitTF](https://gittf.codeplex.com/) or Git TFS 
Android Studio will work with Git and then you will need to do push and pulls using command line. Which can be totally worth it

Answer (score 1):

There is now a plugin available for integrating TFS with Android Studio. I haven't tried it but it says it will work with Android Studio. You can read more about it in this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/10/23/visual-studio-team-foundation-plugin-for-intellij-and-android-studio/) from Microsoft.